# In wp_list_comments comment dates won't work?

Tags: comments, date

I'm trying to create my first comments list and comment form in my wordpress site but the dates are displayed as `%e %B %Y at %H:%M` instead of the date.

It seems like the `date format` isn't recognized.

I've simply written this code:

```
<?php
    $args = array (
        'avatar_size' => 48
    );
    wp_list_comments($args);
?>
<?php comment_form(); ?>
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Does this still happen after you disabled all plugins?

Comment: I haven't try it, I take a look

Comment: thank you, it was qTranslate a plug-in, which needed to set time options.

Comment: Then add this as answer and mark the question as _answered_.

Comment: do you mean to write the answer by myself? if you write it I'll flag as the right answer

Comment: You’ve found what caused the problem, so you can write the answer. It is okay to write [answers to your own questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9933/is-there-a-convention-for-accepting-my-own-answer-to-my-own-question). You may get a [badge](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/badges/13/self-learner) for that. :)

Comment: Write your answer now. Please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from comments:

The plugin qTranslate cannot parse the time format string if no time options are set. Disabling the plugin or setting the time options fixes the problem.